# Hiding Vertical Navigation Pane in ASP.Blazor

Tags: c#, html, css, navigation, blazor

So I am trying to display a navigational pane vertically using blazor and devexpress controls , the devexpress controls Form Layout already does the resizing and changes the navs orientation from horizontal to vertical, however i cannot get the vertical navigation to be hidden using a button click. Note I cannot use any plugins due to copyright's etc... if anyone can assist thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share your existing code, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to hide a component on button click. Your dev express control can go in where ShowHideComponent is.

Main Component:

```
@page "/test"


<button @onclick="(() => ShowComponent = true)">Show</button>
<button @onclick="(() => ShowComponent = false)">Hide</button>
@if (ShowComponent)
{
    <ShowHideComponent></ShowHideComponent>
}


@code {
    bool ShowComponent { get; set; } = false;
}
```

`ShowHideComponent.razor`:

```
<div>Show Or Hide This</div>
```